# Extracting data from struct sk_buff

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, kernel

I'm attempting to extract data from a `struct sk_buff`, but have not received the output I am expecting. The frame in question is 34 bytes; a 14-byte Ethernet header wrapped around an 8-byte (experimental protocol) header:

```
struct monitoring_hdr {
    u8      version;
    u8      type;
    u8      reserved;
    u8      haddr_len;

    u32     clock;
} __packed;
```

After this header, there are two, variable-length hardware addresses (their lengths are dictated by the `haddr_len` field above). In the example here, they are both 6 bytes long.

The following code extracts the header (the struct) correctly, but not the two MAC addresses that follow.

**Sender side:**

```
    ...
    skb = alloc_skb(mtu, GFP_ATOMIC);
    if (unlikely(!skb))
            return;
    skb_reserve(skb, ll_hlen);
    skb_reset_network_header(skb);
    nwp = (struct monitoring_hdr *)skb_put(skb, hdr_len);
    /* ... Set up fields in struct monitoring_hdr ... */
    memcpy(skb_put(skb, dev->addr_len), src, dev->addr_len);
    memcpy(skb_put(skb, dev->addr_len), dst, dev->addr_len);
    ...
```

**Receiver side:**

```
   ...
   skb_reset_network_header(skb);
   nwp = (struct monitoring_hdr *)skb_network_header(skb);

   src = skb_pull(skb, nwp->haddr_len);
   dst = skb_pull(skb, nwp->haddr_len);
   ...
```

**Expected output:**

I used tcpdump to capture the packet in question on the wire, and saw this (it was actually padded to 60 bytes by the sender's NIC, which I've omitted):

```
0000 | 00 90 f5 c6 44 5b 00 0e  c6 89 04 2f c0 df 01 03
0010 | 00 06 d0 ba 8c 88 00 0e  c6 89 04 2f 00 90 f5 c6
0020 | 44 5b
```

The first 14 bytes is the Ethernet header. The following 8 bytes (starting with `01` and ending with `88`) should be the bytes put into the `struct monitoring_hdr`, which executes correctly. Then, I am expecting the following MAC addresses to be found:

```
src = 00 0e c6 89 04 2f
dst = 00 90 f5 c6 44 5b
```

**Actual output:**

However, the data that I receive is shifted two bytes to the left:

```
src = 8c 88 00 0e c6 89
dst = 04 2f 00 90 f5 c6
```

Can anyone see a logical flaw in above code? Or is there a better way to do this? I've also tried `skb_pull` in place of `skb_network_header` on the receiving side, but that resulted in a kernel panic.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**SOLUTION**:

The pointer to the first byte of the data in the `sk_buff` was not being pointed to by `src` as it should have been. I ended up using the following:

```
   ...
   skb_reset_network_header(skb);
   nwp = (struct monitoring_hdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
   skb_pull(skb, offsetof(struct monitoring_hdr, haddrs_begin));

   src = skb->data;
   dst = skb_pull(skb, nwp->haddr_len);
   ...
```

Comment: How do you define src and dst?  How are you accessing the bytes to display them?  Just wondering if you are casting directly to an integer type which may have an alignment issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, Ben. `src` and `dst` are both `u8 *`, and to view their contents I'm doing a `printk("%02x:%02x...", src[0], src[1]...)` to just print out every byte.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [skbuff.h header](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/linux/skbuff.h), the functions you are using look like this:

```
static inline void skb_reset_network_header(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        skb->network_header = skb->data - skb->head;
}

static inline unsigned char *skb_network_header(const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        return skb->head + skb->network_header;
}

extern unsigned char *skb_pull(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len);
static inline unsigned char *__skb_pull(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
{
        skb->len -= len;
        BUG_ON(skb->len < skb->data_len);
        return skb->data += len;
}
```

So first, I would try printing out `skb->data` and `skb->head` to make sure they are referencing the parts of the packet you expect them to.  Since you are using a custom protocol here, perhaps there is a bug in the header processing code which is causing `skb->data` to be set incorrectly.

Also, looking at the definitions of `sky_network_header` and `skb_pull` makes me think perhaps you are using them incorrectly.  Shouldn't the first 6-byte addr be at the location pointed to be the return value of `skb_network_header()`?  It looks like that function adds the length of the header block to the head of the buffer, which should result in a pointer to your first data value.

Similarly, it looks like `skb_pull()` adds the length of the field you pass in and returns the pointer to the next byte.  So you probably want something more like this:

```
src = skb_network_header(skb);
dst = skb_pull(skb, nwp->haddr_len);
```

I hope that helps.  I'm sorry that this is not an exact answer.

Comment: Although it didn't quite fix the problem, you've given me some insight into what to look at (and motivated me after about 6 hours of little progress). Many thanks!

Comment: If you figure out any more I'd be interested in seeing the results.

Comment: After taking a break from this project, I came back to it and managed to fix it-- the solution is above. Thanks again for the help.