# Capture TCP packet in linux kernel programming

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am working on Linux(ubuntu 14.04). I want some typical information about linux kernel programming.

In TCP Communication, when the linux kernel is creating a packet by encapsulating headers, I want to capture the packet when it going from Network Layer to Ethernet Layer (not through wireshark).

Encapsulation:

1. Application Data(A_Data) is created.
2. TLH(Transport Layer Header) is added in A_Data.
3. NLH(Network Layer Header) is added in Step 2.
4. Eth(Ethrenet Layer Header) is added in Step 3.

I think for each step a kernel module is dedicated(I am not sure). If it that so I want to know which module is doing step 3, Which module is transferring that packet to step 4 i.e Ethernet Layer.

I have a kernel source code i.e. linux-3.13.0.

I want to get the NAT Firewall code.

Comment: what's your specific question then ?

Comment: I want to get in NAT Firewall code

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to analyze source code.

- In **static** code analysis, you do not have running system:

  - Use [Kernel Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/) and good books that describe kernel internals. My favorite is Robert Love's "Linux Kernel Development", but "Understanding Linux Network Internals" as @user2699113 suggests.
  - You may read code, and use Cross-Reference systems like http://lxr.linux.no/+trees. They allow to quickly walk over functions and definitions by clicking hyperlink.
- In **dynamic** code analysis, you add some probes and tracers to running kernel, like [LTTng](http://lttng.org/). My favorite is [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/)

---

I know that function `dev_queue_xmit(struct sk_buff*)` is responsible for sending a packet over a network. Let's say its preliminary knowledge collected through both of methods I presented. Let's dig into `struct sk_buff*` to seek for corresponding device-level handler:

```
struct sk_buff {
    ...
    struct sock     *sk;
    struct net_device   *dev;
    ...
```

So let's capture some info behind struct net_device with SystemTap:

```
# stap -e 'probe kernel.function("dev_queue_xmit") { 
        printf("symname: %s\n", 
            symname($skb->dev->netdev_ops->ndo_start_xmit)); 
        print_backtrace(); }' --all-modules
...
symname: tg3_start_xmit
0xffffffff813277b8 : dev_queue_xmit+0x0/0x7 [kernel]
0xffffffffa02482e2 : br_dev_queue_push_xmit+0x163/0x169 [bridge]
0xffffffffa024672a : br_dev_xmit+0x1be/0x1db [bridge]
0xffffffff8132726f : dev_hard_start_xmit+0x23b/0x315 [kernel]
0xffffffff813276b6 : __dev_queue_xmit+0x36d/0x46a [kernel]
0xffffffff81353690 : ip_finish_output2+0x226/0x29a [kernel]
0xffffffff81354dcd : ip_queue_xmit+0x270/0x29b [kernel]
0xffffffff81366d6c : tcp_transmit_skb+0x6f9/0x72a [kernel]
0xffffffff81367cd1 : tcp_write_xmit+0x802/0xa20 [kernel]
0xffffffff81367f3f : __tcp_push_pending_frames+0x24/0x50 [kernel]
0xffffffff8135de79 : tcp_sendmsg+0x6af/0x7c9 [kernel]
0xffffffff813121df : sock_write_iter+0x7c/0xa1 [kernel]
0xffffffff81138510 : new_sync_write+0x6a/0x8e [kernel]
0xffffffff811392aa : vfs_write+0x9c/0x11e [kernel]
0xffffffff811394f4 : sys_write+0x51/0x85 [kernel]
0xffffffff813e6449 : system_call_fastpath+0x12/0x17 [kernel]
```

Now you have names of functions that a responsible for transferring packets and go deeper if you want, i.e. `tcp_write_xmit` is a TCP-layer function, `ip_finish_output2` is a IP-layer function and `br_dev_queue_push_xmit` with `tg3_start_xmit` are device-level functions.

If you wish to capture packet's data, you may to bind to one of that functions and extract data from `sk_buff` (i.e. see here: [Extracting data from struct sk_buff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664783/extracting-data-from-struct-sk-buff))

Also note that most of the functions have `[kernel]` suffix which means that no separate module is responsible for them. That is because *module* term in Linux is quite broad: most Linux subsystems may be statically linked with `vmlinux` ("main module") if corresonding CONFIG option as value `y` instead of `m`.